# Comparing Pandas Dataframe's matching rows and column for differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I'm wondering which is the best way to compare every cell of two dataframes, only for cells that matches the first dataframe rows and columns, as an example:

df1 =

[image]

df2 =

[image]

My desired output is to get every cell change between the two dataframes for rows of df2 with the same item name and for columns in df1 that exists in df2, in this case:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to perform this for a bigger dataframe rather than two loops are welcome.

Comment: please include your sample data as text, not as an image. it makes it very difficult to use as is.

Comment: Please [don't add data or code as pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). You can use `print(df1)` and copy and paste the output in your question.

Comment: Ok, didn't knew about that. Will do next time, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) to do what you want.

Like in this example :

```
import pandas as pd

df_before = pd.DataFrame({'item':['A','B','C', 'D'], 'value':[1,2,3,4]})
df_after = pd.DataFrame({'item':['A','B','C', 'D'], 'value':[1,1,3,5]})

melt_before = df_before.melt(id_vars=['item'], value_vars=['value'], var_name='column')
melt_after = df_after.melt(id_vars=['item'], value_vars=['value'], var_name='column')

diff = melt_before.merge(melt_after, on=['item', 'column'], suffixes=('_old', '_new'))

print(diff[diff['value_old'] != diff['value_new']])
```

It prints the following Dataframe :

```
|--|----|------|---------|---------|
|  |item|column|value_old|value_new|
|--|----|------|---------|---------|
|1 |  B |value |2        |1        |
|3 |  D |value |4        |5        |
|--|----|------|---------|---------|
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, didn't knew this function. Thanks!